# I want a query to extract the table data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Items table:

```
ItemNo, Description, BaseUnitOfMeasure, UnitPrice
-------------------------------------------------
  1     Prod1           pc                200
  2     prod2           pc                150
  3     prod3           pc                120
```

ItemsLedger table:

```
ItemNo, Quantity
----------------
  1        400
  1        -20
  1        -5
```

Above are my two tables and I want to extract the data in a format below

```
ItemNo, Description, BaseUnitOfMeasure, UnitPrice, Quantity
------------------------------------------------------------
  1        prod1            pc             200       375
```

I tried this query but didn't work

```
SELECT 
    item.[No_],
    item.[Description],
    item.[Base Unit of Measure],
    item.[Unit Price],
    SUM(ledger.[Quantity])
FROM 
    items AS item
LEFT JOIN
    ItemLedger AS ledger ON item.No_ = ledger.[Item No_] 
GROUP BY
    item.No_
```

but it didn't work. Ignore typos and table names etc.

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* what does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired beahviour? Something else? Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you need to include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT i.[No_], i.[Description], i.[Base Unit of Measure], i.[Unit Price],
       Sum(il.[Quantity])
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     ItemLedger as il
     ON i.No_ = l.[Item No_]
GROUP BY i.[No_], i.[Description], i.[Base Unit of Measure], i.[Unit Price]
```

Comment: Are there SQL dialects where you don't have to include them ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I believe that MySQL allows this to some extent.

Comment: It does, @RBarryYoung , but it's not recommend. I, and many others, really dislike the fact that MySQL promotes such laziness.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I don’t like it either, I was just answering Peter’s question.

Comment: I know, @RBarryYoung , I was just confirming that it *does* (your comment implied uncertainty), but also adding additional context.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez . . . Yes.  In fact, if the `No_` is declared as the primary key or unique, then the SQL standard also supports only using the `id` in the `group by`, while keeping other columns.  MySQL and Postgres both support this standard functionality.